# Reading data from multiple urls using BufferedReader

Tags: java

I have two static blocks in my class that load data from two URLs. I want to use a single static block, and read the data efficiently. Any thoughts on how this can be done?

```
static {    

    URL urlA = null;
    String data = "";       
    try {
        url = new URL(urlA);            
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlA.openStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            data = data + inputLine;
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //Do stuff with the data
}

static {    

    URL urlB = null;
    String data = "";       
    try {
        url = new URL(urlB);            
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlB.openStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            data = data + inputLine;
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //Do stuff with the data
}
```

Comment: Uhm, it is not really recommended to use static blocks for that...

Comment: Go ahead, you have our permission.  You could simple write a single, static, utility method and pass in the different URLs

Comment: What kind of improvements do you want?

Comment: I need to use static blocks in this case since I want the data to be loaded as soon as the class is loaded. Ha MadProgrammer :)

Comment: justhalf - Just want to combine everything in one static block, which would mean creating multiple String variables, starting two different while loops. I am thinking if this can be done more efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Improvements:

1. Do not use a `static` initializer block for this. These are executed when the class is loaded. You can't know when that will happen, and if something goes wrong the class fails to load, and the class loading error confuses the original error. Use a  `static` utility method instead and call it "lazily" when the data is needed.
2. Use `StringBuilder` instead of `String` to concatenate the output. String being immutable means that every time you append a line the program must copy what has been read so far into a new string, causing a major performance hit:

   ```
   StringBuilder input = new StringBuilder();
   String inputLine;
   while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
       input.append(inputLine);
   }
   data = input.toString();
   ```
3. Handle the exceptions properly. What happens if the program is not connected to a network? You will get an `IOException`, the program will print a stack trace somewhere, and then what? No data has been loaded from anywhere so there's nothing to process.
4. The character encoding. The program assumes the remote system uses the character encoding that happens to be the default encoding on the local system.  If you're in complete control of where the program will be run this doesn't have to be a problem, but it's safer not to make such assumptions and use some fixed well known encoding instead, like UTF-8. Set the encoding in the InputStreamReader constructor.

Comment: I have a logger. I will be using it. This is just a dummy implementation I typed up here to get y'all's input.

Comment: Using a logger is besides the point, what's important is if it's meaningful to continue the execution after loading the data has failed. Since you're loading the data you must *need* it for something, right?

Comment: Yup, but thats besides the point. Not relevant to the question I have asked here ;)

Comment: If you want answers relevant to your problem you should ask a question that's relevant to your problem. Asking "How to improve this code that has nothing to do with what I'm actually doing" doesn't seem very productive.

Answer (score 0):

You can have something like this:

```
static {    

        String dataFromUrl1 = loadFromUrl("http://myurl1");
        String dataFromUrl2 = loadFromUrl("http://myurl2");
    }


private static String loadFromUrl(String urlStr){
    String data = "";       
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlStr);            
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            data = data + inputLine;
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
        mue.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
    return data;

}
```

Here you have a static function which gets data from a given url and returns it. you can call this static function as many times you want from the static block.

Comment: Yes if the return type is a string. What is url1, and url2 both return objects of different types? In my case, they actually do.

Comment: what are the expected return types then?

Comment: Objects custom to my application.

Comment: Be specific in your questions. Couldn't you mention in your question that you want get different objects from different urls? My suggestion is to write static function which converts a url data to the desired object, and access the same from static block. But this kind of data loading in the static block is not considered as a good practice.

Comment: Nope. I didn't have to. Even if I did, your implementation is very generic.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
public static String readUrl(String urlString) {    

    String data = "";       
    try {
        url = new URL(urlString);            
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            data = data + inputLine;
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return data;
}

public static String data1;
public static String data2;

static {    

data1 = readUrl("http://google.com");    
data2 = readUrl("http://oracle.com");

}
```